# How to add navigation property manually model first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties, ef-model-first

I have a table with books and a table with authors created by model-first.
There's a navigation property in Books table pointing to AuthorID
(because each book has an author)
here i'm trying to fill in the tables with values and it's okay when it comes down to scalar properties. But how to add a value to navigation property?
My navigation property is called AuthorBook[image]

```
 Book book1 = new Book();
 Author author1 = new Author();
author1.Surname = "Dickens";
 author1.Name = "Charles";
 db.AuthorSet.Add(author1);`
hbook1.Title = "Great Expectations";
book1.Genre = "Novel"
db.BookSet.Add(book1);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

'

Comment: Shouldn't Book to Author be * -> *?

Comment: @AluanHaddad what do you mean?

Comment: That books typically can have multiple authors. Maybe not in your domain though.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
var rel = new AuthorBook { Book = book1, Author = author1 };
book1.AuthorBook.Add(rel);
```

that obviously goes before `SaveChanges();`

Comment: And how to fill in another navigation property? the connection is One-to-many
Many books in one location
I have created location already
`Location location1 = new Location();
 location1.Floor = "2";
location1.Cupboard = "3";
location1.Section = "1";
location1.Shelf = "2";
location1.Row = "1";
db.LocationSet.Add(location1);`

I tried to fill in location the same way as you suggested to write AuthorBook but visual studio underlines it with red. And AuthorBook is nor underlined, which is good

Comment: if the location exists you'll need to select it first and then add it to the book (as the author).

Comment: But I can't add it by writing the same code as for the author

Comment: var location = db.Locations.Where(x => x.Floor == floor && x.Cupboard == cupboard && ...).SingleOrDefault(); if (location == null) location = new Location { Floor = floor, Cupboard = cupboard, ... }; book1.Location = location;

Comment: I added your suggested code (but location instead of locations) and it says it can't resolve symbol Location

Comment: This answer tackles your *original* question. You shouldn't "hijack" an answerer by adding new questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
Book book1 = new Book();
book1.Title = "Great Expectations";
book1.Genre = "Novel"

// Add 1 or more authors
Author author1 = new Author();
author1.Surname = "Dickens";
author1.Name = "Charles";

// AuthorBook better be a collection since a book can have 1 or many authors
book1.AuthorBook.Add(author1); 

db.BookSet.Add(book1);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The above code will create one record in `Book` table, 1 in `Author` and one in `AuthorBook`. You do not need to manually add an item in code to `AuthorBook` since EF will take care of that for you.

Comment: No, if i write like that `book1.AuthorBook.Add(author1);`  visual studio underlines author1

Comment: underlines and says what?

Comment: Argument Type "WpfApplication1.Author" is not assignable to parmeter type "WpfApplication1.AuthorBook"

Comment: That means your model is set up incorrectly. As I said in my comments, your `Book` should have a navigation property which is a collection of `Author` types. Otherwise your model is not correct. You have a many to many here, so read [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) for more info.

Comment: @CodingYoshi The name of the navigation property should be `Authors`, the `AuthorBook` type/table is not really a domain concept it is just relational boilerplate.

Comment: Then add it to that

Comment: So does that answer your question?

Comment: @CodingYoshi No, the model is set up correctly. Book should *not* have a collection of Authors. That would mean that any author can only have one book. Frankly, I don't understand why the other answer isn't marked as accepted.

Comment: @GertArnold Just because Book has a collection of Authors does not mean that an author can have one book-they can have many books. See [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)